# Running R on amazon EMR with spark 1.6 and Zeppelin 0.5.6

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, sparkr, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to setup the R interpreter to run in Zeppelin which is currently running on EMR. Zeppelin is working perfectly and I am able to write script in Scala and Python. When I use %r, %sparkR or %knitr I receive an error : "r interpreter not found"

The applications which I have running in my emr-4.7.2 cluster are: Hive 1.0.0, Zeppelin-Sandbox 0.5.6, Spark 1.6.2, Pig 0.14.0

Within the interpreter there is no mention of R so figure I am missing something but do not know what.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's just not available on AWS EMR yet, not even with emr-5.0.0.

Comment: thanks eliasah.... Here's hoping it come available soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeppelin on Amazon EMR (till at least emr-5.0.0) does not support the SparkR interpreter.

You ought following the [Elastic Map Reduce Release Guide/Zeppelin documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-zeppelin.html) to get more information.

Comment: :( and still not supported in emr-5.8.0 "Zeppelin on Amazon EMR does not support the SparkR interpreter."
They don't give a reason either.